# Get database Value in textboxFor in bootstrap modal popup in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I place a text box in the bootstrap modal popup and also I have a kink in the table data in the table come from database so I want when I click pop-up show database cell value in the textbox that exists in the modal-popup. Below is my code

Thats my action method that gets data and data is passing to the ViewBag.Type

```
public JsonResult LinkButton(int RoelID)
{
    Role model = new Role();
    Session["State"] = RoelID;
    int id = RoelID;
    RoleServices ser = new RoleServices();
    var data = ser.Get(id);          
    bool result=false;
    if(Session["State"]!=null)
    {
        ViewBag.Type = data.RoleType;
        result=true;
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Here is a code of JQuery and Ajax acall the action method on link click

```
<a href="#"  onclick="UpdateID(@item.RoelID)">Select</a>

<script>
    var UpdateID = function (RoelID) {
        $("#hiddenID").val(RoelID);
        var roleID=$("#hiddenID").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '@Url.Action("LinkButton", "Account")',
            data: { RoelID: roleID },
            success:function()
            {
                $("moReg").modal('hide');
            }
        })
        $("#moReg").modal('show');
    } 
</script>
```

Here is textBox in the Modal PopUp

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoleType, new { @value=ViewBag.Type })
```

Comment: Very little of this makes sense. Your assigning a value to `ViewBag` but returning a `JsonResult` (`ViewBag` is for passing data to a view). If you want to return `data.RoleType` back to the view, then its `return Json(data.RoleType, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Then if you want to assign that to the textbox, in the success callback its `success:function(data) { $('#RoleType').val(data);` }` (and remove `new { @value=ViewBag.Type }` from your textbox)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank You its solve my problem  i am new in CS field let me ask a Question if i have more than two textboxes and also have CheckBoxes how assign multiple value to View

Comment: Then just return an anonymous object containing the values your want - `return Json(new { id = 1, name = 'abc', .... });` and access it using `var id = data.id; var name = data.name;` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Alot ... God bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return your data like bellow,

```
return this.Json(new { result = true, Type = data.RoleType }, 
                      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then in your ajax success method, you can retrieve the value like,

```
success:function(data)
{
 var _result = data.result;
 var _Type = data.Type ;
}
```

Comment: Thank You its solve my problem i am new in CS field let me ask a Question if i have more than two textboxes and also have CheckBoxes how assign multiple value to View

Comment: In that case, you can create a Model class, for example "MyTextBoxNCheckBox" and assign all the properties that you want to show in your view and return that in json return. So simple :)